# weblogic.jar on Dockerized Weblogic is empty

Tags: java, docker, ant, weblogic

I am trying to dockerize `Weblogic 12.2.1.3` and deploy applications with `Ant`.

I faced multiple issues and after research I realised that `weblogic.jar` on `/u01/oracle/wlserver/server/lib` is empty.
[image]

In addition, there isn't any other `weblogic.jar` on the container and the console of Weblogic is accessible with servers running.

I am trying to understand why is it empty and how can I generate it on the container. A workaround would be to retrieve the `jar` and add it but it's not optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WLS 12c, weblogic.jar is a "manifest only" java library.
If you take a look at the MANIFEST.MF file you will find a class-path entry including all jars required by WebLogic Server to run.